# UiButton and translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

**My question is a simple one.**

I'm currently subclassing `UIButton` to create some custom animations. However, when I set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, my view moves to the upper left corner. However when I set it to false OR change the class to `UIView` or `UIControl` this problem doesn't appear anymore.

**Here is my code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let button = TestA(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.view.addSubview(button)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}


class TestA : UIControl {


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}


}
```

**Does anyone know what's going on?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have position `A` for example and position `B`. For position A  you have added constraints and its fixed on its place. If you just type for example `button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0.100.100)` it will not move from current position because it is fixed, in this case if we want to achieve movement we need to use `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and we should set it to true, after that we have possibility to change position of `UIButton`. Hope it helps.

Comment: First of all my apologies, I should've added the code for review. The frame is hard-coded in all circumstances as `button.frame = CGRect(100,100,100,100)` regardless of whether it's a `UIButton`, `UIView` or `UIControl`. However, this behavior manifests only when it's a `UIButton`.

Comment: translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints this works on uibutton,UiView and so on but if you have hard coded position and you are trying to unlock constraints it will jump on x:0, y:0 .